# echo|set /p=foo > foo.txt sets %ERRORLEVEL%

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch

I've noticed some very strange behaviour when trying to write text to a file without having the trailing new line. There is code everywhere which looks like that:

```
echo|set /p=foo > foo.txt
```

It works great but my build system fails on that because when I evaluate %ERRORLEVEL% I get a 1 after the call:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
echo |set /p=foo>foo.txt
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

returns

```
D:\>echo 0
0

D:\>echo   | set /p=foo  1>foo.txt

D:\>echo 1
1
```

Is this a known behaviour? Is `set` getting picky because there is no variable to set?

**Note:** The echoed code of `echo |set /p=foo>foo.txt` is actually `echo   | set /p=foo  1>foo.txt`

Comment: As far as I know, that is the case. `set /p` will set errorlevel to 1 because no input is given, whether you use a variable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Regejok for the hint. Searching for `set` is not the easiest task though :D

However citing this source: https://ss64.com/nt/set.html it seems that this indeed causes error level to be set to 1:

```
Errorlevels

    When CMD Command Extensions are enabled (the default)

    If the variable was successfully changed %ERRORLEVEL% = 0
    No variable found/invalid name = 1
    SET /A Unbalanced parentheses = 1073750988
    SET /A Missing operand = 1073750989
    SET /A Syntax error = 1073750990
    SET /A Invalid number = 1073750991
    SET /A Number larger than 32-bits = 1073750992
    SET /A Division by zero = 1073750993
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on the same issue.

After playing a little with the `set /p` command I found that it would rise %ERRORLEVEL% in two cases: when there is no variable name, and when user input is empty.

I used the trick to strip quotes from string, and for me providing a dummy variable name was just enough to fix:

```
$ echo | set /p DUMMY="Some string with spaces and quotes" > log.txt
```

And then checking that it actually works:

```
$ echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
$ type log.txt
Some string with spaces and quotes
```